# Como trabajar con decimales en shell linux, uso del condicional if & else

Tags: linux, bash, algoritmos, shell

Estoy trabajando en un código que permita saber la clasificación de un estudiante mediante una nota ingresada en shell linux, mi problema es que no he podido ajustar el valor a cifras decimales, si uso la "," el programa corre pero no funciona bien.

adjunto mi código

```
echo   Este programa muestra si aprobó o no un estudiante
echo "Ingrese nota a"
read numeroa


#-----------------Numero---perdio-----------------------

if (( $numeroa >= 1 && $numeroa <=2,9));
  then
   echo perdio
  fi

#-----------------Numero--Aprobó---------------------

if (($numeroa >= 3))
  then
   echo Aprobó
  fi


exit 0
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí el error al trabajar con decimales:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: seguramente espera un `.` en vez de `,` para el separador de decimales

Comment: al trabajar con "." ni siquiera ejecuta el programa

Comment: ya vale, estaba pensando en `| bc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como bien comenta [Patricio Moracho](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/31764/patricio-moracho) bash no soporta cálculos con números no enteros (aritmética de punto flotante o "con decimales")

Si el requerimiento de precisión es de un sólo dígito prueba multiplicando por 10, algo así:

```
read numeroa; 
if (( $numeroa * 10 >= 10 && $numeroa * 10 <= 29 )); 
  then echo "perdio";
fi
```

---

Otra forma es usando un programa externo auxiliar [`bc`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/bc.1.html) para que haga la comparación, algo así:

```
read numeroa;
if (( $(echo "$numeroa >= 1 && $numeroa <= 2.9" | bc -l) ));
 then echo "perdio";
fi
```

---

Bonus

Si querés usar la `,` como separador de decimales onda el `2,9` lo filtras con otro programa auxiliar [`sed`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/sed.1.html) , algo así:

```
read numeroa;
if (( $(echo "$numeroa >= 1 && $numeroa <= 2,9" | sed -u 's/,/./g' | bc -l) )); 
  then echo "perdio";
fi
```

Comment: El problema básico es que BASH no soporta aritmética de punto flotante, sería bueno que lo dejaras claro en tu respuesta, por eso hay que recurrir a programas externos como `bc`. La primer solución servirá únicamente cuan dotrabajas con un decimal. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias :) si me funcionó, lo tendré en cuenta sobre bc